# I'm getting 500 error when testing the ChromeWebStore API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm getting a 500 error when testing the [User License API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/userLicenses/getUserLicense)

Manifest

```
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "clientidobv",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
  "key": "*****keyobvhere",
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/"
```

After grabbing the token with a userflow, I run:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/' + chrome.runtime.id);
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
console.log(req.responseText)
req.send()
```

I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

- Chrome Runtime ID is the same as the one in the API console
- The token was checked & is valid
- I'm testing locally but with a user who has an active licence in production

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here, might have to resort to in-app payments instead

Comment: @MaximGeerinck did you find the solution? I'm facing with the same issue :(

Comment: No, currently integrating in-app payments

Comment: @MaximGeerinck Same issue :( Please share your solution if you got one. Thanks you!

Comment: Didn't find a solution for this, we used the in-app api instead