# CWS Payment API internal server 500 error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-oauth

There seem to be general issue with the Chrome Web Store API / Userlicenses which returns 500 internal server error for every new extension that want to use the google payment gateway inside their extension.

However, when trying to check the license the following URL  https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/my-extension-id-in-web-store returns Status Code 500.
Full response: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}],"code":500,"message":"Backend Error"}}

Another developers I found that has the exact same issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123485216
[I'm getting 500 error when testing the ChromeWebStore API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487006/im-getting-500-error-when-testing-the-chromewebstore-api)

Steps to reproduce:
Add a new project to https://console.developers.google.com, enable Chrome Web Store API, get the OAuth 2.0 credentials for Chrome App, add the client ID to the manifest of the Chrome extension
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "the-generated-client-id",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]}

I have tried many times the https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment official guide, yet no succesful results.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sending in a bug report on the [correct platform](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry) as what was suggested in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123485216?

Comment: @Staafsak did you find a solution? I'm stuck with the same issue :(

Comment: @Staafsak Same issue :( Please share your solution if you got one.
Thanks you!

Comment: @Daniyar I am afraid not, I used a whole different method of doing authentication etc